# Anyone can tell me what type of resistor and what is ohm and watt of this resistor?

Tags: pcb

I have this burned resistor and dont know the value of this resistor. [image]

Comment: 1 ohm. Doesn't really look burned to me, bit toasty perhaps. Did you measure it ?

Comment: The value reads on the resistor.

Comment: Yes, may its 1 ohm, may i know the watt of this resistor? What is 30 stated on this resistor? Is that its watt?

Comment: The power could be estimated better with an estimate of the length and diameter. My guess is it is closer to 3 watts than 30.

Comment: We need to know how big it is before we can estimate the power rating, and even then it's a guess.  Re-take your picture with a ruler next to the resistors.  Or measure the length of the body (not the leads) and include that in your question.  Or find a resistor manufacturer or distributor and find something similar that's the same size. They're almost certainly vitreous enamel resistors, which tend to be small for their power rating.

Comment: Thanks all of the answer, may i know what type of resistor is this? I can found it on google. The closer i found is it look like vitreous enamel, wirewound or carbon film resistor.

Comment: ^^ You can't know 100% for sure unless you take it apart or can positively identify the manufacturer & series by the markings (there are no visible markings in your photo, but maybe there's something underneath?)    I also second the notion, this is not "burned", but it's clear this is something that runs hot.  I've seen far far more charred resistors that work fine.  If I were looking at this PCB, I wouldn't give that resistor a second thought unless my ohmmeter told me it was bad.

Comment: Thanks for the advice kyle B, this pcb's age is about 30years, took it to electronic shop and they cant identify this resistor.

Comment: All right, thanks all, i will test it with multimeter 1st, its my mistake didnt measure it and judge it burned by its looks. Thanks x100000.

Comment: It's 1\$\Omega\$ +/-5%. It has gotten hot but it may or may not be open.